# Linux - Running commands into a remote server from a client

Tags: linux, scp

My ask is to copy a .py file from my client machine to a remote server and then running the .py script into the remote server.

Note: I need to perform the same for n number of servers so basically I am here looking to create a kind of automation script which will do the same.

From my colleagues I came to know that in order to achieve automation, password less login is a must (kind of a prerequisite).

In order to achieve the same, I first copied a public key into my remote server (manually), then created a script which does scp to copy the shell script from client to remote. And the shell script is responsible for running the .py file.

Adding the public key and scp worked for me.

Kindly do let me know if adding the public key is actually needed for achieving the automation for this task .

I am a beginner in LINUX world, so if possible please elaborate the answer while replying.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Linux/UNIX box with ssh key based login
Script=/home/linuxadmin/installer_linux.py
Destination=/home/linuxadmin/script
time=`date`
output=/home/linuxadmin/output_mainscript/
USERNAME=abc@some.com
PASSWORD=12345


#Loop For Installing software on multimple servers
for f in `cat host.txt`;
do
    scp $Script $f:$Destination  ### Copying file from source to destination
    echo "-------- start time "$time"echo "----------"" | tee -a $output/mainscript_log.txt
    sshpass  ssh $f "sudo /usr/bin/python $Destination/installer_linux.py --no-prompt -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD " | tee -a $output/mainscript_log.txt ### Executing files on Destination
    echo "-------- End time "$time"echo   "----------"" | tee -a $output/mainscript_log.txt
done
```

Comment: If you want elaborate answer, you need to write an elaborate question. From what you said it is not even clear whether the `scp` worked without password. If if did, what is the part you need help with? If it didn't, what exactly did it ask for (there may also be passphrase for the private key) and how did you copy the private key (so somebody can check whether you did it correctly or not). Without exact commands and exact output we can't tell what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: For the stated question, the answer is simply yes, copying the key is necessary, because that's how you will be authenticated (unless you have Kerberos and are being authenticated via ticket). However, it's not just/really copying; you have to put the key in the list of authorized keys.

Comment: You may want to take a look to ansible, it can do the job: https://github.com/ansible/ansible

Comment: You can just ssh and login to the server and issue the command what u want. There are plenty of information about connecting ssh using IP.

Comment: @JanHudec - Yes, adding public key and scp worked for me. I wanted to make sure, that adding key is needed so that I can pass on the same information to the client. Updated the question as well

Comment: 1.) **Never write passwords in script files.** 2.) **Never write passwords in program arguments!** Program arguments are public on Unix systems and can easily be displayed with `ps -ef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kindly do let me know if adding the public key is actually needed for
>   achieving the automation for this task .

Yes, you need to copy the public key of the main/controller node (the one you intend to execute scp from) to all the other nodes/servers.

---

**Suggestion 1**:
I am assuming, you want some solution for not a just one time task, but a long term management (correct me, if I get it wrong).

Use a configuration management tool - as per your case a single management node, and merely deploying .py scripts,

I'd recommend using Ansible. With Anisble you can start with a controller node, making an inventory (list of hosts/machines), and share the controller's public key on all the nodes/machines.

And all you need to do (once the setup is there, which is pretty simple) - is update the playbook, or even execute a command for all the servers from the controller/main server.

---

Here's few very plain English blogs to get started with:

- [**How to install Ansible**](http://devopspy.com/devops/install-ansible-on-centos-7/).
- [**Getting started with Ansible**](http://devopspy.com/devops/getting-started-ansible/).

---

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of above blog posts.

Comment: Looks very helpful. Let me first try it out and then let you know.

Comment: Yh, you better. As it'll provide consistency, scalability and minimal management.

Comment: Does it apply true for CentOS as well?